# How to get Form Control using variable declaration

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

We are using Form Validation for our forms, the issue comes with the amount of code needed to get the control again and perform checks on it, for example to check if a control is not valid to show an error we have `<input formControlName="someinputname" required...><div *ngIf="!form.get('someinputname').valid"></div>`.

Examples I have seen on the internet show using variable declaration to easily get the value, for example `<input ([ngModel])="var" #test="ngModel"> <div *ngIf="test"></div>`, the problem with this is we do not bind a value using `ngModel` only by `formControlName`. With this formControlName I don't seem to be able to do `#someinput="ngControl"` (not sure of exact syntax) because an error is produced `[Angular] There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngControl"`.

We have a shared module which imports and export `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`, the shared module is also imported into the module specific to this page - so the component should have access to both form modules.

Anyone have any ideas?

Found this: http://iterity.io/2016/05/01/angular/angular-2-forms-and-advanced-custom-validation/ - so changing my `ngControl` to `ngForm` still produces the same error `[Angular] There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"`